# Eliminate pause in transitions between animations in AnimationSet

Tags: android, animation

I have an AnimationSet which moves around a view in a rectangular way:

```
private void animate(final View viewToAnimate) {
    final AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);

    TranslateAnimation animationOne = new TranslateAnimation(0, ((int) HelperPixel.convertDpToPixel(this.getApplicationContext(), 70)), 0, 0);
    animationOne.setDuration(500);

    TranslateAnimation animationTwo = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, ((int) HelperPixel.convertDpToPixel(this.getApplicationContext(), 140)));
    animationTwo.setDuration(1000);
    animationTwo.setStartOffset(500);

    TranslateAnimation animationThree = new TranslateAnimation(0, ((int) HelperPixel.convertDpToPixel(this.getApplicationContext(), -140)), 0, 0);
    animationThree.setDuration(1000);
    animationThree.setStartOffset(1500);

    TranslateAnimation animationFour = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, ((int) HelperPixel.convertDpToPixel(this.getApplicationContext(), -140)));
    animationFour.setDuration(1000);
    animationFour.setStartOffset(2500);

    TranslateAnimation animationFive = new TranslateAnimation(0, ((int) HelperPixel.convertDpToPixel(this.getApplicationContext(), 70)), 0, 0);
    animationFive.setDuration(500);
    animationFive.setStartOffset(3500);

    animationSet.addAnimation(animationOne);
    animationSet.addAnimation(animationTwo);
    animationSet.addAnimation(animationThree);
    animationSet.addAnimation(animationFour);
    animationSet.addAnimation(animationFive);
    animationSet.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animationSet);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    });

    viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animationSet);
}
```

My problem now is that there is a small but very obvious pause between those animations. I don't want that. I want a smooth transition between the animations so that the user thinks it is one animation. He should not see that there are several animations.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: [This page](http://androidsourcehelp.com/avoid-flickering-in-android-animation-smooth-transition-animation/) suggests creating a small animation with 0 bound transition after the animation ends. Could you try this?

Comment: have you found a solution?